# How to remove many (200 000) files?

Tags: ubuntu, shell, terminal, remove

I must remove 200 000 files (all of them) from a folder, and I don't want to delete the folder itself.

using rm, I get an "Argument list too long" error.
I've tried to do something with xargs, but I'm not a Shell Guy, so it doesn't work:

```
find -name * | xargs rm -f
```

Comment: Why don't delete the folder and recreate it after deletion?

Comment: @garconcn Just reading this 9 years later. I don't remember why I had this problem in the first place, but I would guess either I didn't provide the full context to make the question readable, or...  that's was a good idea.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
$ find /path/to/folder -type f -delete
```

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that GNU find (as used by most Linux distributions) can delete files on its own using `-delete`.  This also avoids problems with files containing quotes or newline characters (though you could use GNU find's `-print0` and GNU xarg's `-0` options to fix that).

Comment: @DerfK, nice remark! Also, lots of ppl tend to play with `xargs` meanwhile `find` has `-exec command {} +` syntax.

Answer (score 5):

You are doing everything right. It is the **'*'** that gives you a problem (the shell is expanding it into list of files instead of the `find`). The right syntax could be:

```
cd <your_directory>; find . -type f | xargs rm -f
find <your_directory> -type f | xargs rm -f
```

(The latter is a bit less efficient since it will pass longer names to `xargs`, but you will hardly notice :-) )

Alternatively, you could escape your **'*'** like this (however in that case it will also try also remove "." and ".."; it is not a biggie - you will just get a little warning :-) ):

```
find . -name '*' | xargs rm -f
find . -name "*" | xargs rm -f
find . -name \* | xargs rm -f
```

If your file names contain spaces then use this:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you have a filename containing a space.

Comment: @lain: Yes, I was just in a process of editing my answer to include the trick for white spaces :-)

Answer (score 3):

The following command will delete all files from the **current** directory:

```
find . -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: `-name '*'` doesn't mean "all files". Files are said with: `-type f`

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
find /path/to/folder -type f -print0  | xargs -0 rm -f
```

or

```
find /path/to/folder -type f -exec rm -f "{}" +
```

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to quantas answer, here are some additions.

If you like to delete files with a particular name pattern you can write it like this. Also added -print so you can see what's happening as the files are being deleted.

```
sudo find /home/mydirectory -name "*.jpg" -type f -print -delete
```

This for instance deletes all jpegs in mydirectory.